# A variation of the Ryll-Nardzewski fixed point theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory, fixed-point-theorems

Is there a fixed-point theorem that implies the following result?

> Let $F$ be a nonempty convex set of functions on a discrete group with values in $[0,1]$. Suppose $F$ is invariant with respect to left shifts and closed with respect to the pointwise convergence. Then $F$ contains a constant function.

This statement looks like [Ryll-Nardzewski fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryll-Nardzewski_fixed-point_theorem), but it does not seem to follow from the theorem.

Comment: For amenable groups, the result should follow from a theorem by Mahlon Day; if $X$ is a locally convex topological vector space and $G$ is an amenable group that acts affinely and continuously on a compact convex subset $C$ of $X$, then this action has at least one fixed point.

Comment: My group is free; in particular, it is not amenable.

Comment: This doesn't seem true. Let $F$ be the free group on $\{a,b\}$ 
and $X\subset F$ be the words whose last letter is $a$ or $b$. 
Let $\xi=\delta_a+\delta_b-\delta_{a^{-1}}-\delta_{b^{-1}}\in\ell_1(F)$. 
Then for any $s\in F$, 
one has $\langle 1_X,s\xi\rangle\geq1$. 
Hence the pointwise-topology closed convex hull of $F1_X$ cannot contain constant functions.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA yes, looks like a counterexample -- I need to think about it. BTW, is it a standard example?

Comment: @Anton Petrunin: It's my standard way of doing it via the Hahn-Banach theorem. It suggests to look at some $G$-orbit in $\ell_1(G)\cap\{1\}^\perp$. I tried the simplest among the non-amenable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The claim does not hold. Let $F$ be the free group on $\{a,b\}$ and $X⊂F$ be the words whose last letter is $a$ or $b$. Let $\xi=\delta_a+\delta_b−\delta_{a^{-1}}−\delta_{b^{-1}}\in\ell_1(F)$. Then for any $s\in F$, one has $\langle 1_X,s\xi\rangle\geq1$. (To see this, view $F$ as the $4$-regular tree and $s\xi$ as a signed characteristic function of the $1$-neighborhood of $s\in F$.) Hence the pointwise-topology closed convex hull of $F1_X$ in $\ell_\infty(F)$ cannot contain constant functions.

Comment: Narutaka, excuse me, "whose last letter is $a$ or $b$" - doesn't this mean that $X=F$?

Comment: @Sergei Akbarov: I mean not $a^{-1}$ nor $b^{-1}$ (nor $\emptyset$).

Comment: Ah, OK, thank you!

Comment: It seems that if the set is invariant with respect to left AND right shifts, then the answer is yes. It does not look like an interesting statement, but does it follow from some theorem?

Comment: @Anton Petrunin: Very interesting. Perhaps, you could post another problem. I do not know which pairs $H \le G$ has the property that every nonempty $G$-invariant pointwise-closed convex set of functions on $\ell_\infty(G/H)$ contains a constant function. By following a standard recipe, one can find several equivalent conditions, but none seems easy to check.

Comment: I posted it. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404616/trans-amenability-of-group-actions

Answer (score 9):

The claim does not hold, as the nice example by Naratuka Ozawa shows.
The purpose of this answer (or rather, extended comment) is to share a related fixed point theorem.

**Theorem:**
Let $X$ be a non-empty set endowed with two structures:

1. The structure of a compact convex set, that is a convex structure and a compatible compact topology $T$ such that continuous affine functionals separate the points.
2. The structure of a separable metric space $(X,d)$.

Assume the following compatibility of the two structures: $d$-balls in $X$ are measurable with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra associated with $T$.

If $G$ is a group that acts on $X$ preserving both structures - the convex structure, the topology $T$ and the metric $d$ - then $G$ has a fixed point in $X$.

---

Let me illustrate how the theorem above implies the fixed point theorem of Ryll-Nardzewski: for a non-empty weakly compact subset $C$ in a Banach space, there is a point in $C$ which is fixed by all affine isometries of $C$.

It is enough to show that $C^G$ is non-empty for every countable group of affine isometries $G$. Given such a group $G$, fix a point $c\in C$ and set $X$ to be the norm closure of the convex hull of the orbit $Gc$. Take $T$ to be the weak topology and $d$ to be the norm metric on $X$. We are now in a position to apply the above theorem.

---

*Sketch op the proof:*
As above, we assume as we may that $G$ is countable.
We fix a fully supported probability measure $\mu$ on $G$ and denote by $B$ the corresponding Furstenberg-Poisson boundary. Then the $G$ action on $B$ is amenable and metrically ergodic. By amenability and by 1 there exists a measurable, defined a.e, $G$-equivariant map $B\to X$. By the compatibility of 1 and 2, this map is $d$-measurable, thus by metric ergodicity and by 2 this map must be essentially constant. Its essential image is a fixed point.

Comment: When you say "preserving both structures" it seems literally that $G$ preserves the topology $T$ and the metric $d$ (while not required to preserve the affine structure induced by an embedding as in 1). Is this what you mean?

Comment: @YCor thanks for your comment! In fact, when I wrote up the theorem I had in mind preservation of the convex structure as well, but now when I think of it, it might not be needed by using Tychonoff fixed-point theorem. I will check up the details and update the answer accordingly. Also, I will add a proof, to be safe...

Comment: I clarified and added a proof. The convex structure sure needs to be preserved, e.g there is a fixed point free action of $\mathbb{Z}/2 \ltimes \mathbb{Z}$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Are you assuming that $d$ is preserved? (i.e. the action on $(X,d)$ is isometric)?

Comment: @YCor yes. Isn't it clear from the context?

Comment: No, sorry I even sort of guessed it wasn't (and your example on $[0,1]$ doesn't preserve a metric). Why not say it? it's so easy.

Comment: Ok, Yves, I edited according to your suggestion.

Comment: @UriBader Has this fixed-point theorem been published somewhere?

Comment: @MaoWao, no, afaik.